# Notepad Implementation in c# Status bar menuItem

Tags: c#, textbox, statusbar, multiline, notepad

I'm writing a windows application like a notepad but  in the MDI format.I have found a lot of samples for this but none of them implemented the status Bar which is in the view menu Item,I mean in each notepad there is a menu Item named View and if you click this item you can activate or deactivate the status bar while the word wrap option is not checked,and if you do so the line and column numbers appear in a StatusBarLabel,would you please tell me how should I implement this part of notepad in my application?I found these user-defined properties for this goal but I they don't work for me!

```
public int CurrentColumn
{
     get { return textBox1.SelectionStart - textBox1.GetFirstCharIndexOfCurrentLine() + 1; }
}

public int CurrentLine
{
    get { return textBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(textBox1.SelectionStart) + 1; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I've never used this function, [TextBoxBase.GetPositionFromCharIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.getpositionfromcharindex.aspx) looks like what you need. It gives a Point, which tells me that you'd get both the column and row information from a single function.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Way tooo late to answer but,

As per my understanding about your question, I think you want to implement a status bar also. To do so you can add the control **StatusStrip** from the toolbox to the form where the typing area exist.

After that you'll have to add a Status Label where you'll display the current line number and caret position within the current line, that is the column number. You can Add the label by clicking on the small button and selecting Status Label from the appeared list. It'll look like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9jj2.png):

This is Optional, but you can align status label to right (like it is in Microsoft Notepad) by adding changing the alignment property to Right. If you can't find the the alignment property in Properties Window. You can manually add it in your Form's Designer.cs file by adding the following line:

```
     this.StatusLabel.Alignment=System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemAlignment.Right;
```

You can also add a border to labels left by changing the Border Property to **Etched**

The User Defined Property that you described are used to get the current line and column from the MultiLine TextBox.

As you have mentioned that the properties aren't working for you, you can them in TextBox's **SelectionChanged** event so it constantly get updated while you move the cursor in the TextBox. If you are using these properties that it will look like this.

```
private void TextBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StatusLabel.Text = String.Format("Ln {0}, Col {1}", CurrentLine, CurrentColumn);
        }
```

To hide the Status bar you can toggle its visibility by:

```
StatusBar.Visible=!StatusBar.Visible;
```